# Working with different IEEE floating-point rounding modes in C++

Tags: c++, rounding, ieee-754, idioms

Woe is me, I have to ensure the same floating-point results on a GPU and on the CPU. Ok, I understand IEEE has taken care of me and provided a nice standard to adhere to with several rounding options; and the CUDA part is sorted out (there are intrinsics for the different rounding modes), so that's just motivation.

But in host-side C++ code - how do I perform floating-point arithmetic in a specific rounding mode (and I mean in a specific statement, not throughout my translation unit)? Are there wrapper functions which use assembly under the hood? Is there a set of classes for floating point number proxies with the different rounding modes?

I'm also asking the same question about the translation-unit level. How do I make the compiler (gcc/clang/MSVC) default to a certain rounding mode when compiling a translation unit?

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos, but you may be able to set it http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround (or find out that you can't and regroup)

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos, yes I seem to have misread your comment as being unable to set it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Following a lead from @AndreasPapadopoulos , it looks like [there is an official way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) to change the rounding mode:

```
int fesetround(int round)
int fegetround()
```

but there are several caveats:

1. This is C++11, not C++98 (although in practice you could probably just use your system's `<fenv.h>` which is C99.
2. It requires communicating with the compiler via `#pragma` 's
3. This switching might be slow.

I'm not sure how widely this is used in practice (and whether there are any nicer abstractions around it which are in more common use).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of handling this is to introduce a class that sets the rounding mode on its initialization and resets it to the previous mode when it goes out of scope, like so:

```
#include <cfenv>

//Simple class to enable directed rounding in floating-point math and to reset
//the rounding mode afterwards, when it goes out of scope
struct SetRoundingMode {
  const int old_rounding_mode;

  SetRoundingMode(const int mode) : old_rounding_mode(fegetround()) {
    if(std::fesetround(mode)!=0){
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set directed rounding mode!");
    }
  }

  ~SetRoundingMode(){
    // More recent versions of C++ don't like exceptions in the destructor
    // so you may need a different way of handling issues here.
    if(std::fesetround(old_rounding_mode)!=0){
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to reset rounding mode to original value!");
    }
  }

  static std::string get_rounding_mode_string() {
    switch (fegetround()) {
      case FE_DOWNWARD:   return "downward";
      case FE_TONEAREST:  return "to-nearest";
      case FE_TOWARDZERO: return "toward-zero";
      case FE_UPWARD:     return "upward";
      default:            return "unknown";
    }
  }
};
```

You can then use this like

```cpp
void foo(){
  const auto srm = SetRoundingMode(FE_UPWARD);
}
```

Note that all the rounding modes are listed within the class.