# Is there a C equivalent to CUDA rounding mode compiler intrisics?

Tags: c, floating-point

In CUDA I frequently use rounding mode compiler intrinsics, as documented here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/#rounding-modes

I'm looking for C equivalents to CUDA commands such as:

```
  __fadd_[rn | rz | ru | rd] (x, y)
```

I've read about `fsetround`, as documented here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround, but are there more specific (and possibly faster) commands, equivalent to those in CUDA?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39202713/681865

Comment: Hi talonmies, thanks. Indeed, I am aware of that question, but this is a bit more directed.

Comment: A comment for this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202940/is-there-a-direct-host-side-equivalent-to-cudas-floating-point-rounding-mode-in), of which this question appear to be a duplicate, mentions that `AVX512` has support for static rounding modes (and presumably, Intel offers intrinsics to access them). But I don't think there is main-stream processor yet that uses `AVX512`?