# How do you std::round doubles, but round towards zero in halfway cases?

Tags: c++, floating-point, std, rounding

I am in a situation where I need to round 0.5 and -0.5 down to 0. So I checked various documentations -

The generic C++ methods seems always round 0.5 away from 0.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

While if I go the lower level way by setting rounding style, it seems a very global approach and could potentially have threading and CPU state implication which is quite annoying.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/float_round_style

Is there a light-weight, standard library and simple way to achieve rounding down to 0?

Comment: `std::round(std::nextafter(x, 0.f))` could work for small numbers. But for large numbers with insufficient precision, it could mess up the result.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 As a rule of thumb across multiple languages - I would try not to use any features which has potential implication beyond local function, and `fesetround` is clearly such one. Yes your statement might be correct but there can also be platform issues, compiler bugs and implementation pitfall which make it not hold, especially in a language like C++.

Comment: maybe ```std::trunc```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My numbers are sufficiently small so I don't need to consider cases like `INF` or `std::numeric_limits::max()`. Is this good enough?

Comment: @waffentrager I'd still need to round 0.51 up though. But yeah I can do a multiply then division.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202713/working-with-different-ieee-floating-point-rounding-modes-in-c

Comment: @Alex Considerations like " I don't need to consider cases like `INF` or `std::numeric_limits::max()`" deserve to be in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
T absmax(T a, T b)
{
    return std::abs(a) > std::abs(b) ? a : b;
}

template <typename T>
T round_ties_towards_zero(T x)
{
    return absmax(std::round(std::nextafter(x, T(0))), std::trunc(x));
}
```

For sufficiently small numbers you don't need `absmax(..., trunc(x))`. Without it, I start getting wrong answers for `double`s at around `1e16` and larger.

Comment: Thank you! Only 1 question: the documentation says `nextafter()` would signal underflow case too - but if I know the input is a valid `double` I shouldn't have such issue right?

Comment: @AlexSuo You could get an underflow by giving it a number right next to 0. But it says it returns the correct answer when it underflows, and I think it doesn't matter if it also sets errno in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You can decompose a number into the integral and fractional part with [`std::modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf). You can then build your own rounding mode on top of that:

```cpp
template <std::floating_point T>
T round_to_nearest_ties_to_zero(T x)
{
    T integral;
    T fractional = std::modf(x, &integral);
    if (std::abs(fractional) <= T{0.5}) {
        return integral;
    }
    return integral + std::copysign(T{1}, x);
}
```

Comment: To avoid wider math than needed, maybe `fractional <= T(0.5)`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it should make no difference for an optimizing compiler, but the naive codegen might be worse tbf. `T{0.5}` would be best imo.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, one wants to apply `round()`, i.e. round-to-nearest-ties-away, *unless* a tie case is detected, in which case one wants to apply `trunc()`, i.e. round-towards-zero. The simplest way to detect tie cases is to compute the absolute difference between `x` and `round(x)` and check whether it equals one half.

This algorithm is used in the C++11 code below, which I tested by using a three-way comparison with the two implementations proposed in the existing answers. No mismatches were found.

```cpp
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
T round_to_nearest_ties_toward_zero (T x)
{
    T rx = std::round (x);
    T tx = std::trunc (x);
    return (std::abs (x - rx) == T(0.5)) ? tx : rx;
}
```

On many platforms `std::round()` maps neither directly to a hardware instruction nor an inlined instruction sequence, but instead is a library call. If performance is a major concern, one could easily emulate `std::round()` as the addition of a rounding offset followed by `std:trunc()`. For a templated implementation the rounding offset would ideally computed as `constexpr T rndofs = std::nextafter (T(0.5), T(0));` but I find that compilers do not accept that. I have tried to work around this in *semi-portable* fashion in the code below.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

template <typename T>
T round_to_nearest_ties_toward_zero (T x)
{
    constexpr int dm1 = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits - 1;
    constexpr T rndofs = T((1ULL << dm1) - 1) / T((1ULL << dm1)) / 2;
    T rx = std::trunc (x + std::copysign (rndofs, x));
    T tx = std::trunc (x);
    return (std::abs (x - rx) == T(0.5)) ? tx : rx;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Eliminate one routine call with `T rx = std::round(x); return std::abs(x-rx) == T(.5) ? x-rx + x : rx;`.

Comment: The name is properly toward zero, not to zero.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Small nitpick: `trunc(-0.5)` returns -0, but the replacement `(x-rx)+x` returns +0 for x=-0.5. That is likely harmless in most contexts, but probably best to point it out.

Comment: That’s one paper, not established practice, although Muller, Lauter, and Boldo are leaders in the field. For the augmented operations they refer to, the IEEE 754-2019 standard has “roundTiesTowardZero.” This comes up in committee discussions sometimes, and use of "to zero” is generally regarded as a slip and is corrected. When we have a tie and round it to even, meaning we round it to the candidate with the even low digit, we actually round it **to** the even-digit candidate; that candidate is the result…

Comment: … When we have a tie and round it down, we do not round it **to** zero (except in the particular case where zero is the actual result), we round it to the candidate that is nearer zero, hence, **toward** zero. (I see you edited since your initial comment, so this is just informative.)

Answer (score 0):

Variation on [@Jan Schultke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78091880/2410359) and [@njuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78092158/2410359) approach:

```
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
T round_to_nearest_ties_toward_zero (T x) {
    T tx = std::trunc(x);
    return std::abs(x - tx) <= T(0.5) ? tx : tx + std::copysign(T(1.0), x);
    // or 
    return std::abs(x - tx) <= T(0.5) ? tx : std::round(x);
}
```